# How to parse json response using fetch API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Am trying to display json response after calling an API using `fetch`, I can see the response in the response tab of chrome, but I can't find it in fetch response object

**Client side**

```
   import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      query: '',
      properties: []
    }
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // const { query } = this.state.query;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });

  }


  search() {
    console.log('fetching data')
    try {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/property/find', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'CORS',
        body: JSON.stringify({ "query": this.state.query }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data)
          this.setState({ properties: data.result });
        })

    }
    catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  }


  render() {

    const { properties } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App" >


        <input type="text" name="query" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>

        <div className="form-group">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.search}>Search</button>
        </div>

        <div className="row text-center">

          {properties.items &&
            properties.items.map((property, index) =>
              <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4" key={index}>
                <div className="card h-100">
                  <img className="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x325" alt="" />
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h4 className="card-title">  {property.details.description}</h4>
                    {/* <p className="card-text">{property.biography}</p> */}
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-footer">
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Find Out More!</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )

          }


        </div>


      </div>
    )

  }
}

export default App;
```

**Server side**

```
var app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

var db = require('./db');

var property = require('./endpoint/property');
// var authController = require('./auth/AuthController');


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3001');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    next();
});

//allow OPTIONS on just one resource
// app.post('*', cors())
app.use(cors())

app.use('/property', property);
```

**End point response**

```
      var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

var Model = require('../model/propertyModel');


// GETS A SINGLE USER FROM THE DATABASE
router.post('/find',function (req, res) {
  var query = req.body.query

  console.log(query)


  Model.find(   {  $text: { $search: query }} ,  { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).then((data)=>{

   if(data.length>0){

    res.status(200).json({"result":data});
   } 
   if (data.length==0){

    Model.find({ "details.description":  {$regex:query}  }).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).then((data)=>{

      if(data){
        res.status(200).json({"result":data});
       } 
       if (data.length==0) return res.status(404).send("No properties found.");



    })

   }


  })


});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like in the chrome dev tools network tab?  Also, is the client side logging `data`, or is it going to the catch clause returning the error?

Comment: I have edited the question, added more details for server and screenshots

Comment: You're still not showing the property endpoint code.

Comment: You should also show us how you are trying to render that data into the DOM.. the way in which you are trying to render the received data is most likely your issue.

Comment: @MattOestreich, also the result is received when I tried on postman

Comment: @Exorcismus thats my point. Your issue is most likely with how you are trying to render the JSON data.. which you are not showing us. Please update your question with the client side code that renders the data into the DOM.  We need to see more of your React Component.

Comment: @Exorcismus do you have React dev tools chrome extension? To see if `properties` state field is set after the API call returns. Also including the client-side render method code (how that properties field is being used) will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the render method, it looks like `properties.items` is expected to be an array. But in the network tab response screenshot, the `result` field inside the JSON response is an array.

Calling `this.setState({ properties: data.result });` will lead to `properties` being the field you should be mapping over in the render method, instead of `properties.items`

Answer (score 2):

Inside your render method, if you change this:

```
{properties.items &&
            properties.items.map((property, index) =>
```

...to this:

```
{properties &&
            properties.map((property, index) =>
```

That should resolve this for you.